# How to skip data resource block in case of empty variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
variable "privateSubnets" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     =  [
   ""
 ]
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = toset(var.privateSubnets)
  id       = each.value
}
```

I am trying to get private subnets CIDR's data (Private subnets will be passed while execution if any)  but in some cases the private subnets will be empty, in that case I am getting below error
**Error:** multiple EC2 Subnets matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Subnet

Is there anyway to skip data block execution in this empty subnets scenario?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear, because if `var.privateSubnets` is empty (as you state and the values are the subnet IDs), then the lazy evaluation of the iterator would then result in no `data.aws_subnet` being Read. Also if the the private subnets are empty, then why do multiple subnets match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a validation rule to tell Terraform that an empty string is never valid as a subnet ID:

```
variable "private_subnets" {
  type = set(string)

  validation {
    condition     = alltrue([for s in var.private_subnets : s != null && s != ""])
    error_message = "All subnets must be non-null strings with at least one character."
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = var.private_subnets

  id = each.value
}
```

With that validation rule, Terraform will mark the caller's value for this variable as invalid if it contains any elements that are not valid subnet ids, which should therefore achieve a more relevant error message than the one about matching multiple subnets.

---

If for some reason it's important to just silently ignore the invalid items rather than returning a validation error, you could alternatively strip them out using a `for` expression:

```
data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = toset([
    for s in var.private_subnets : s
    if s != null and s != ""
  ])

  id = each.value
}
```

However, I would typically prefer to tell the caller they did something wrong rather than to just silently fix it, because the upstream problem might be just one side-effect of a more important problem and hiding the error here would make it harder to understand what went wrong.